# Adjust flex items in same column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a horizontal slider(scrollable) on my page, which contains list of sub-cards. The below code snippet works perfectly fine.

JSFiddle-1: https://jsfiddle.net/28rnwpqk/

[image]

I now want to display different sized cards, which are dynamic. I made following change to my container css, so as to stack multiple cards in same column if space exists.

```
.container {
  ...
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  ...
}
```

JSFiddle-2: https://jsfiddle.net/k60zLg74/

[image]

This results in the parent container width being set only to width of first slider item, bcz of **flex-direction: colum**n property. As such the background color, slider scroll has stopped working. What is the correct way to achieve this without impacting width of container. My main requirement is to have flex items stacked vertically if space exists and size of cards is not know upfront.

Comment: Why do you need `width: max-content` to `.container`?

Comment: In actual scenario, I have flippers on click of which the items slide. The sliding happens based on width, which should be equal to that of all slider items [including not in viewport]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS grid can do this better:

```css
.viewport {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  grid-auto-flow:column;
  grid-template-rows:1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-columns:130px;
  gap: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  min-width:100%;
}

.item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  grid-row:span 2;
}
.item.small {
  grid-row:span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item small">3</div>
    <div class="item small">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `width: max_content;` setting is restricting the width of your container. Remove that property, and your full container will have a blue background as expected:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: The width is needed in this case for the scroll functionality to work. The width of container should be equivalent to width of all slider items [including not in viewport]